# Converting C# Graph into a proper mathematical graph

Tags: c#, math, graph, coordinates

Recently, I have been working on this graphing system in C#, and I am having problems with the coordinate system. As we all know, C# uses the top left corner as 0,0 coordinates. What I want to accomplish is to make 0 in the middle of the windows form.

Currently, this is what I have...

[image]

As you can see, `0,0` is on the top left, making the center of the graph `400`. So is there a way to transform the coordinates into a proper mathematical graph coordinate?

I hope I was able to explain this situation well as my English is not very well.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static int _wWidth;
    public static int _wHeight;

    int mouseX, mouseY;

    Point _center = new Point(_wWidth / 2, _wHeight / 2);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            c.MouseDown += ShowMouseDown;
        }
        this.MouseDown += (s, e) => { this.label3.Text = "{X: " + e.X + " Y:" + e.Y + "}"; mouseX = e.X; mouseY = e.Y; };
    }
    private void ShowMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = e.X + ((Control)sender).Left;
        var y = e.Y + ((Control)sender).Top;

        this.label3.Text = x + " " + y;
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ClientSize = new Size(800, 800);
        int windowWidth = this.ClientSize.Width;
        int windowHeight = this.ClientSize.Height;

        _wWidth = windowWidth;
        _wHeight = windowHeight;

        button1.Location = new Point(_wWidth - button1.Width,0);

        //AllocConsole();  /***** Enable console for debugging *****/
    }


    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    public void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        _drawPlain(e);
    }
    public void _drawPlain(PaintEventArgs e){

        Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();

        for(int x = 0; x < _wHeight; x+=50)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(80, 75, 75)), new Point(0, x), new Point(_wWidth, x));
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green; if (x == 20) { Console.Write("X - "); } Console.WriteLine(x);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(x.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.White), new Point(_wWidth/2,x));
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < _wWidth; y += 50)
        {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(80, 75, 75)), new Point(y, 0), new Point(y, _wHeight));
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; if (y == 20) { Console.Write("Y - "); } Console.WriteLine(y);
                int num = y;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(num.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.White), new Point(y, _wHeight/2));

        }
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Green, new Point(0, _wHeight/2), new Point(_wWidth, _wHeight/2));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.DarkRed, new Point(_wWidth/2, 0), new Point(_wWidth/2, _wHeight));

        //e.Graphics.DrawString("0", new Font("Arial", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.White), new Point(_wWidth / 2, _wHeight / 2));


        //// Create pen.
        //Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        //// Create points that define polygon.
        //Point point1 = new Point(100, 200);
        //Point point2 = new Point(300, 200);
        //Point point3 = new Point(200, 50);
        //Point[] curvePoints =
        // {
        //     point1,
        //     point2,
        //     point3
        // };

        //// Draw polygon to screen.
        //e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(blackPen, curvePoints);
    }
    public static int _yCellCount()
    {
        int _cell = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            _cell++;
        }

        return _cell;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow,new Point(mouseX,mouseY),new Point(_wWidth/2,400));
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code which you are using, please

Comment: @ASh How would I be able to post long code? Should I edit my post and add it?

Comment: Of course there is. Just subtract (400,400) from all your coordinates. You'll want to have this calculated dynamically depending on the size of your window.

Comment: @germi I have edited my post with the code I am using, (its quite messy...) I have predefined ClientSize manually making it 800,800.

Comment: I suggest you make new draw functions. ie myDraw(x,y, graphHeight, graphWidth, graphPosX, graphPosY)